# How to backup a system restore point

Tags: windows-7, system-restore

Is there any application that I could use to backup system restore points in windows 7?
Or do you know where restore points are saved when you create them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restore points are hidden in the "System Volume Information" folder, the folder itself may be hidden.

You are better off using 3rd party backup software like Acronis. Make a full disk Image and use the incremental backup feature. Store the image on an external usb hard drive.

http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/index.html